# fopen working for some urls but not others

Tags: php, fopen

I am using fopen to check the existence of an image file (and as a precursor for extracting the image from the external url).

It is working perfectly fine for most images, for example,

SY300.jpg">http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51DbiFInDUL.*SY300*.jpg

But it is not working for images from a website like Victoria's Secret, for example:

http://dm.victoriassecret.com/product/428x571/V360249.jpg

Is this a permissions problem? And if so, is there any work around?

```
$url = "http://dm.victoriassecret.com/product/428x571/V360249.jpg";
$handle = @fopen($url,'r');
if($handle !== false){
return true;
}
```

For successful link, $handle returns "Resource ID #11", but for unsuccessful link like Victoria's Secret, $handle returns nothing.

Additionally, exif_imagetype is not returning anything for the images (we have the exif extension installed).

Is there any work around for this? We are building a bookmarklet that allows users to extract pictures from sites. We noticed that other bookmarklets are able to get around this (i.e. Pinterest) and are able to get the pictures from Victoria's Secret.

Comment: Can you update with the code snippet of how you're using `fopen`?

Comment: I know that for IIS services, the IIS server user must have permission on the file to open it. So for exemple if victorias IIS dont have permission to open/create/edit... the victoria secret server wont let you. It might also be true for services other than IIS. (which sadly none come to my mind right now)

Comment: He isn't talking about IIS and I'm not sure on which operating system he is using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's don't show a data due to hotlink protection defined in .htaccess file. You need to grab a data as a client. I tried you can using CURL if you put HTTP header information of user agent read contents and save to file.

In my solutions your problem is solved.

Note: Be note for filetype on remote server that are using in header, there are for an example GIF file `image/gif` so you can put another filetype example for PNG.

**Example of solution that WORKS:**

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

$url = "http://dm.victoriassecret.com/product/428x571/V360249.jpg";

function getimg($url) {         
    $headers[] = 'Accept: image/gif, image/x-bitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg';              
    $headers[] = 'Connection: Keep-Alive';         
    $headers[] = 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8';         
    $user_agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)';         
    $process = curl_init($url);         
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);         
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);         
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);         
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);         
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);         
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);         
    $return = curl_exec($process);         
    curl_close($process);         
    return $return;     
} 

$imgurl = $url; 
$imagename= basename($imgurl);
if(file_exists($imagename)){continue;} 
$image = getimg($imgurl); 
file_put_contents($imagename,$image);
```

Note: If you are on Linux filesystem be sure that root folder is writeable (CHMOD) otherwise will not save a file in a path.

And so you are talking about EXIF data, and how is CURL downloaded image is identical to orignal I've checked with md5sum between original image on victoriasecret server and downloaded using CURL. However, a results are SAME, IDENTICAL so you can grab and analyzing downloaded data for future... and delete if you don't need anymore.

On a Linux platform you can use for testing identical files by sum of md5 result using **md5sum**:

```
md5sum V360249.jpg V360249_original.jpg
893a47cbf0b4fbe4d1e49d9d4480b31d  V360249.jpg
893a47cbf0b4fbe4d1e49d9d4480b31d  V360249_original.jpg
```

A result are same and you can be sure that exif_imagetype information is correctly and identical.

Answer (score 0):

By removing the @ symbol, I was able to get a more meaningful error:

```
Warning: fopen(http://dm.victoriassecret.com/product/428x571/V360249.jpg) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! in [removedSomedatahere]/test.php on line 5
```

It does similar in curl, wget, and fopen with no other options set. I would hypothesize that this has something to do with cookies or other setting not being set, <strike>but I don't have a direct answer for you</strike>. Hopefully that helps a little.

**[Edited - Solution based on comments]**
So it appears that using curl may be a better option in this case if you also set the user agent. The site was blocking based on the user agent. So the solution is to set a commonly used browser as the agent.

Here is an example of setting the user agent:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
```

Please see [this link](http://davidwalsh.name/set-user-agent-php-curl-spoof) to understand how to set the user agent in curl.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried some tests using http://www.htaccesstools.com/test-hotlink-protection/ and it is not indicating that the images are hotlink protected.

Comment: There are solution, called user agent and CURL.